# Spring Roo addon: Why ProjectOperations.isProjectAvailable() returns false?

Tags: spring-roo, add-on

I'm developing an addon for Spring Roo and when I try to add a dependency to a target project the operation fails with a "not allowed" message. I've noticed that this operation depends on a validation that uses **ProjectOperations.isProjectAvailable(name)** and that this call is returning false (the method is receiving the correct name).

I don't know which are the conditions to pass this test. I'm executing Roo shell inside the directory of my target project and this one has been created with a Roo script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. Being positioned on the project I want to modify, I have to use isProjectAvailable(""). Passing null also returns true.